# Can node.js be used in raspberry pi to stream video?

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

I just got my Raspberry Pi camera. I want to stream video from the Pi. Would Node.js be the right choice to start looking at ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

NodeJS can be used on the Raspberry Pi. [Here is a nice tutorial on how to use nodejs on your Pi](https://web.archive.org/web/20131125222921/http://blog.rueedlinger.ch/2013/03/raspberry-pi-and-nodejs-basic-setup).

As for should it, I'd probably use whichever technology works well on the Pi and you know how to use. If you already know node then it might be a good fit.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks! I felt node.js could be light weight and fast on Raspberry Pi. I will give it a shot.

Comment: Link appears to be dead :(

Comment: @Cort3z thanks for the catch, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Great! Can't wait to give it a go